# Luggage-only insurance when traveling around the world?

Tags: luggage, international-travel, insurance

I want an insurance that covers my belongings only.
I already have a international travel health insurance, hence I do not need some link or recommendation to do-it-all packages (i.e. insurance for health + rescue + belongings).

Note: my credit card does NOT cover my belongings, nor does any of the insurances I already have.

Ideally, I'd like to find an insurance that can insure my belongings regardless of my nationality & residence.

Links to information of **quality** is welcome.

Comment: Coverage for personal possessions while traveling usually is only available as part of a travel insurance package.  I have never seen it sold as a stand alone product.  Some homeowners / renters insurance policies may cover your possessions outside the domicile.  And most every insurance company will take your nationality and residence into consideration when quoting a price.

Comment: @Tom usually yes, but I did find several insurances providing coverage for belongings/luggages only.

Comment: Unless you drag about very expensive items for a backpacker, I would not worry. Have in insurance on your laptop/tablet/phone and do without for the rest. The most important part of any travel insurance, in my view, is the repatriating part, which will not come with a luggage insurance.

Comment: Two reasons I'd querey the logic/validity of doing this: The first is - even if these packages exist, are the actually any cheaper? If so, great, if not, then why not be overinsured rather than pay the same for a less comprehensive product. The second is that travel insurance covers a lot more than just medical and property - typically you also get liability and cancellation cover, as well as repatriation, all of which **can** be pretty valuable, even if you don't need the medical.

Comment: @CMaster agreed, getting a package that does cover this as well as health, cancellations and so on would be more ideal. However, there are special cases where one already have these things covered and only need the luggage insurance.

Comment: @Willeke sure, covering the most expensive belongings is good enough. Repatriation is definitely out of topic for this question yes. One should definitely consider it as a top priority, health first of course. But my question is not about whether one should get luggage/belongings insurance, but where to get one. Please try to stay on topic even in the comments, there are already other questions covering the health/repatriation insurance part.

Comment: @AdrienBe My point is that your request seems superflues to me, the part of a traditional travel insurance you can easily do without, often better do without.

Comment: @Willeke haha thx for the input, very productive ;)

Answer (score 1):

Travelex is an insurance company who insure your laggauges too. Travelex y offer protection from trip cancellations and medical emergencies, but also looking after your personal belongings.The trip insurance offers reimbursement for lost, damaged or stolen luggage and belongings. They also provide you with assistance in replacing lost prescriptions, passports or important documentation you need while away.
Thgis link might be helpful: http://www.travelexinsurance.com/

Answer (score 1):

After some research, here are a few I came across.

---

#### For people residing in United Kingdom

[uk.protectyourbubble.com](http://uk.protectyourbubble.com) - UK residents only. up to 180 days.

[photoguard.co.uk](http://www.photoguard.co.uk) - UK residents only?

---

#### For people residing in the USA

http://clements.com/property/default.asp - does NOT seem as clear as it says
This plan covers my camera gear, computer, and other items in my pack from theft or damage anywhere in the world. It’s cheap & covers a lot. I provide receipts for scheduled gear up front (computer, cameras, lenses), and a general amount for unscheduled gear. Cost: Plan 1 (1 year policy) = $19/month for $7500 worth of gear.

---

#### For people residing in Switzerland

[allianz-assistance.ch/content/50/en/baggage-insurance](http://www.allianz-assistance.ch/content/50/en/baggage-insurance) - 2000 CHF insured 92 days for 55 CHF

[erv.ch/fr-CH/clients-prives/assurance-voyages/bagages](http://www.erv.ch/fr-CH/clients-prives/assurance-voyages/bagages) - 2000 CHF insured 1 year for 200 CHF

[fr.april-international.com/global/conseils-informations/assurance-bagages](http://fr.april-international.com/global/conseils-informations/assurance-bagages)

---

#### Resources

- https://nomadforum.io/t/whats-the-best-laptop-insurance-for-european-nomads/972
- https://nomadforum.io/t/how-do-you-insure-your-laptop-when-you-have-already-left-your-country-of-residence/1048
- http://expertvagabond.com/travel-insurance-tips/